# SQLException related to insert database values using ArrayList

Tags: java, prepared-statement, sqlexception

Iam new to java and trying to develop small swing app, I have Inquiry model class which containing getters and setters and constructions and also iam getting input by user in JFrame.

Im getting this error `java.sql.SQLException: At least one parameter to the current statement is uninitialized` "  when run this code.

```
  public class MakeAndReply_Inquiry {

   String IN_ID=null;
   String IN_TITLE=null;
   String IN_MSG=null;
   Date IN_DATE;

    Connection con;
    public void InsertInquiryToDB(ArrayList<Inquiry> arrlist){
        try {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
         IN_DATE = new Date();
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(IN_DATE)); //2014/08/06 15:59:48
        Iterator<Inquiry> iter = arrlist.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext())
            {
            Inquiry inq = iter.next();
              IN_ID=inq.getIn_id();
              IN_TITLE=inq.getIn_Title();
              IN_MSG=inq.getIn_Msg();
            }
            con = new DBConnector().connect();
            System.out.println("nside insert inq Method "+IN_ID +IN_TITLE+IN_MSG);
            String sq = "INSERT INTO INQUIRY (IN_ID,IN_TITLE,IN_MSG,IN_DATE)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement(sq);
            pr.executeUpdate();

         } catch (SQLException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

can some one please help me to solve this.

Comment: Even if invoked from a Swing GUI, the problem description and code snippet suggests it has nothing to do with Swing, so don't add the Swing tag!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting any value in

```
        String sq = "INSERT INTO INQUIRY (IN_ID,IN_TITLE,IN_MSG,IN_DATE)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pr = con.prepareStatement(sq);

        // set values here
        pr.executeUpdate();
```